# CKEditor : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace') Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I render CKEditor on page as below. There is no problem at first, but when I press any key in the textarea and lose focus, it gives the following error. I'm getting this error even though I'm not trying to validate anywhere. Thanks in advance for your answers.

[image: initiliaze]

[image: initiliaze]

[image: error]

Comment: Did you ever figure out what is happening here?  We are getting the same CKE error.